# Is mounting a filesystem as read-only enough to prevent FS/data corruption in case of power loss?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, filesystem-corruption

I have a home-made HTPC setup. I often plug and unplug USB drives on it (be it HDD/SSD or USB memory stick).

I was wondering whether just unplugging these drives without umounting them first would be alright considering that they are mounted as read-only.

I'm not really concerned about uncommitted writes (RO, as I said), but I was wondering if there could be any problem with the electronics of the drive for instance .

Comment: hard drives, SSDs or usb flash keys?

Comment: Mainly usb flash, but if it makes a difference, please enlighten me.

Comment: Short answer, yes. Nothing is written to the filesystem, no write process can be disturbed.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert in the matter, so IMHO: usb flash keys where no part of it is doing writes should survive repeated power loss (unplugging). But there is still a sort of bit rot possible, called [read-disturb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory#Read_disturb).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't even know about read-disturb. But from what I understood from the wiki article, the mitigation for this problem can only be implemented in the firmware of the device. However, the RO state of the drive is a kernel thing (which does not prevent the firmware from doing anything). So this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: What about HDDs then?